# DATETIME search predicate on DATETIME column much slower than string literal predicate

Tags: sql-server

I'm doing a search on a large table of about 10 million rows.  I want to specify a start and end date and return all records in the table created between those dates.

It's a straight-forward query:

```
declare @StartDateTime datetime = '2016-06-21',
        @EndDateTime datetime = '2016-06-22';

select *
FROM Archive.dbo.Order O WITH (NOLOCK) 
where O.Created  >= @StartDateTime
    AND O.Created < @EndDateTime;
```

Created is a DATETIME column which has a non-clustered index.

This query took about 15 seconds to complete.

However, if I modify the query slightly, as follows, it takes only 1 second to return the same result:

```
declare @StartDateTime datetime = '2016-06-21',
        @EndDateTime datetime = '2016-06-22';

select *
FROM Archive.dbo.Order O WITH (NOLOCK) 
where O.Created  >= '2016-06-21'
    AND O.Created < @EndDateTime;
```

The only change is replacing the `@StartDateTime` search predicate with a string literal.  Looking at the execution plan, when I used `@StartDateTime` it did an index scan but when I used a string literal it did an index seek and was 15 times faster.

Does anyone know why using the string literal is so much faster?

I would have thought doing a comparison between a DATETIME column and a DATETIME variable would be quicker than comparing the column to a string representation of a date.  I've tried dropping and recreating the index on the Created column and it made no difference.  I notice I get similar results on the production system as I do on the test system so the weird behaviour doesn't seem specific to a particular database or SQL Server instance.

Comment: The answer is related to how SQL Server recognizes the variable in the query. If SQL is unable to know before running the query what the variable is, it may be unable to use cached plans or guesstimate a new one effectively

Comment: There's a good article from SQLmag on the subject that i think you'll find helpful: [SQLmag -Optimizing Variables and Parameters](http://m.sqlmag.com/t-sql/optimizing-variables-and-parameters)

Comment: @clifton_h: Sorry it's taken a while, been busy at work.  That article you linked to answers my question.  If you'd like to turn your comment into an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All variables have instances that they are recognized.

In `OOP` languages, we usually distinguish between `static`/`constant` variables from temporary variables by using keywords, or when a variable is called into a function where inside that instance the variable is treated as a constant if the function transforms that variable, such like the following in `C++`:

```
void string MyFunction(string& name)
//technically, `&` calls the actual location of the variable
//instead of using a logical representation. The concept is the same.
```

In `SQL Server`, the Standard chose to implement it a bit differently. There are no `constant` data types, so instead we use literals which are either

- object names (which have similar precedence in the call as system keywords)
- names with an object deliminator (including ', `[]`)
- or strings with a deliminator `CHAR(39)` (').

This is the reason you noticed that the two queries produce different results, because those variables are not constants to the Optimizer, which means `SQL Server` will already have chosen it's execution path beforehand.

> If you have SSMS installed, include the Actual Execution Plan (CTRL + M), and notice in the select statement what the Estimated Rows are. This is the highlight of the execution plan. The greater difference between the Estimated and Actual rows, the more likely your query can use optimization. In your example, SQL Server had to guess how many rows, and ended up overshooting the results, losing efficiency.

The solution is one and the same, but you can still encapsulate everything if you wanted to. We use the `AdventureWorks2012` for this example:

1) Declare the Variable in the `Procedure`

```
CREATE PROC dbo.TEST1 (@NameStyle INT, @FirstName VARCHAR(50) )
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM Person.PErson
    WHERE FirstName = @FirstName
    AND NameStyle = @NameStyle; --namestyle is 0
END
```

2) Pass the variable into `Dynamic SQL`

```
CREATE PROC dbo.TEST2 (@NameStyle INT)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @Name NVARCHAR(50) = N'Ken';
DECLARE @String NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @String = 
    N'SELECT *
    FROM Person.PErson
    WHERE FirstName = @Other
    AND NameStyle = @NameStyle';
EXEC sp_executesql @String
            , N'@Other VARCHAR(50), @NameStyle INT'
            , @Other = @Name
            , @NameStyle = @NameStyle    
END
```

Both plans will produce the same results. I could have used `EXEC` by itself, but `sp_executesql` can cache the entire select statement (plus, its more `SQL Injection` safe)

Notice how in both cases the level of the instance allowed `SQL Server` to transform the variable into a constant value (meaning it entered the object with a set value), and then the Optimizer was capable of choosing the most efficient execution plan available.

```
-- Remove Procs
DROP PROC dbo.TEST1
DROP PROC dbo.TEST2
```

A great article was highlighted in the comment section of the OP, but you can see it here: [Optimizing Variables and Parameters - SQLMAG](http://m.sqlmag.com/t-sql/optimizing-variables-and-parameters)

Comment: This helped me a lot. Thanks